# Have UIActivityItemProvider return multiple objects or nothing?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a `Book` class and I want to allow my users to share their progress for each book. To do that I present a `UIActivityViewController`, but I wanted to add different texts for Facebook, Twitter etc., so I had `Book` conform to the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol, and then I can return a different value for its methods depending on the `activityType`. So far so good.

Now I want to *also share an image when the user selects Facebook or Twitter, but just text for all other options*. The methods in `UIActivityItemSource` only let me return one object, though. To share both a string and an image it seems I'd have to add them as different activity items, but then I don't know which `activityType` the user will pick to decide if I should include the image or not.

So how can I share a different number of objects of various classes and values depending on `activityType`?

Thanks in advance,

Daniel

---

Edit: Now I'm trying to do this with `UIActivityItemProvider`… the thing is, sometimes I want to share just some text and sometimes I want to share an image too. So my `UIActivityItemProvider` would have to return multiple objects conditionally (sometimes it would return an image and sometimes it would not) or I would need to use more than one provider and have the image's provider return nil sometimes, but that doesn't seem to be possible. Now what?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to work around my problem. It's not great, though, so I won't accept this answer, but I'll leave it here in case it helps someone.

I can't have a `UIActivityItemProvider` return nil but I can have it return an empty string, so that's what I did – for the `activityTypes` I want an image I return an image, for the ones I don't I return an empty string. Then I have another provider for the text.

There are a few drawbacks, though. Returning an empty string creates a new line, which isn't a deal breaker, but it's annoying. Also there will always be a string item, even if I return an empty string for my text provider, so options like saving to the camera roll won't ever be available.

I'll do this for now, but if anybody has a better suggestion please let me know.

Comment: Why can't you return null? i just tried it and there doesn't seem to be a problem with it... (I return [NSNull null] cuz its safer but it also worked with just play old NULL)

Comment: @Pochi Because `UIActivityItemProvider.item` isn't optional: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityitemprovider/1620457-item

Comment: yes it isn't marked as optional but it isn't specified as non-null. I also found a similar question in the app developer forums and someone also suggested simply returning null. After I tried i myself there doesn't seem to be any issues with it.

Comment: @Pochi Oh, ok… so I think to do what you’re suggesting in Swift I’d have to return NSNull(). I’m on a trip now, but I’ll look into it as soon as I have the chance. Thanks!